# Show error from require failure

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am using Truffle and my contract is migrated fine and I am able to invoke necessary call from `truffle console`

The issue I have is how do I see the failure when a `require` condition is not met. I have this check: `require(msg.sender == creator);`

When making a call that fails the check how do I see a failure in the response? (the `addr2` here is not the creator)

```
truffle(development)> instance.fundEscrow({from:addr2,value:web3.toWei(1,"ether")})
{ tx: '0x51e10...',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x51e10f9a...',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x9cd03...',
     blockNumber: 83,
     gasUsed: 21972,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 21972,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: '0x00',
     logsBloom: '0x0000000000...' },
  logs: [] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output `status: '0x00'` indicates failure.

The instance you deal with is an instance of truffle contract, documented here https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract.

Your call to fundEscrow() returns a promise, which you can resolve as following:

`instance.fundEscrow({from:addr2,value:web3.toWei(1,"ether")}).then(txObj => console.log(txObj.receipt.status)); }`